# Why do all cars seem to use "reflective" paint?

Tags: car

I'm not just talking about "chromed" parts. I mean the whole "paintjob", which seems to be be designed to reflect the environment as to basically be a mirror (somewhat depending on the color).

I don't think I've ever seen a car with "non-mirrory" painting.

Is this just cheaper to do or something? Is it considered more aesthetically pleasing? Is it even a *safety* measure somehow?

I don't understand why cars have to reflect the entire environment, almost as if they were fully "chromed". (I also don't quite understand the purpose of chrome parts.)

Comment: Smooth glossy surfaces are easier to clean with a sponge and a hosepipe than matte surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is a treatment to reduce corrosion - most metals tend to corrode over time.

Many vehicles have been and continue to be produced with non-reflective or matt paint. Military vehicles is one. It is only in relatively recent years that the clear coating has become more common and one practical reason is for protection as it is a tougher protective layer.

It has been available for a long time but the extra expense meant it was a choice made when ordering a new car.

There are some manufacturers offering a matt finish amonst the high end cars as an option over the clear coat as well.